# cache.addAll cannot cache file exept .html

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I have a very disturbing issue with my serviceWorker.js. At the install when I try to cache file, I can only add my .html file, all other trigger my catch error.

```js
self.addEventListener('install', function (evt) {
    console.log('install ', evt);
    caches.open(cacheName)
        .then(function (cache) {
            cache.addAll([
                'index.html',
                'expertises',
                'websocket',
                'results',
                'form',
                'utils.js'
            ]).catch(err => console.error(err));
        });
});
```

In this exemple utils.js isn't add into the cache, and trigger this error `TypeError: Request failed`

I'm using TS, but those js files are present in the Network tab in google chrome

EDIT : In the network tab, util.js trigger a 404

Comment: Is it just utls.js that fails to be cached?

Comment: No all .js, or css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. For anyone that have the same problem.

The TypeError: Request failed, come when the scope of a ressource isn't the good one.

You can check your SW's scope with :

```js
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('../src/serviceWorker.js')
        .then(registration => console.log('scope ', registration.scope))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

For me, my SW scope was `/src` but my file was in `../src`.